# Visual Studio 2019 – Comparing settings to default settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 can be configured in many ways via settings. Is there a simple way to find out which settings differ from the default settings?

I’m looking for a similar method as *Open Settings (JSON)* in Visual Studio Code. *Open Settings (JSON)* in Code only contains the options which differ from the defaults.

What I have tried is the comparison between the exported settings from a new workstation and from an existing one, but the exported xml files contain too much noise.

Comment: "Compare the XML" is what I have done in the path, but as you say: lots of noise (but a decent GUI file differ does help)

Comment: I make the XML usable using an XML indenter (to split those very long lines and get uniform indentation; any proper text editor has this), then use a diff viewer. There might be some noise, but it will be clearly distinct from any actual settings being different